# How to user PopToRootAsync on Master Detail Page?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a master detail page I would like to add a logout functionality (basically a poptorootasync) in that.  For example here is the the list of the menu:
**Client Information** - This will redirect the user to client info page.
**Logout** - This will use the "**await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();**" function.

The problem is I have this ObservableCollection I don't know how to add PopToRootAsync to this

Here is my Code:

```
MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<HomePageMenuItem>(new[]
{
   new HomePageMenuItem { Id = 0, Title = "Client Information", TargetType = typeof(ClientInformationMenu) },
   new HomePageMenuItem { Id = 1, Title = "Logout", TargetType = typeof(**HERE IS WHERE TO PUT POP TO ROOT**) }
});
```

HomePageMenuItem.cs

```
public class HomePageMenuItem
{
    public HomePageMenuItem()
    {
        TargetType = typeof(ClientInformationMenu);
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Type TargetType { get; set; }
}
```

lst selected event

```
private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        HomePageMenuItem item = e.SelectedItem as HomePageMenuItem;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType);
        page.Title = item.Title;

        Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
        IsPresented = false;

        MasterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

Comment: What is HomePageMenuItem?

Comment: @FreakyAli its a class

Comment: And what does that class do?

Comment: As you can see in the Observable collection this sets the title id and target type of the list of menus in the master detail page

Comment: @FreakyAli how can I add a pop to root here?

Comment: Can't you just add one bool that informs you that you need to pop instead?

Comment: Don't feed a `TargetType` just add a bool constructor param that lets you know that you need to pop

Comment: @FreakyAli can you show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HomePageMenuItem would look something like this:

```
public class HomePageMenuItem
{
    public HomePageMenuItem()
   {
      TargetType = typeof(ClientInformationMenu);
   }
    public bool IsHome{ get; set;}
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Type TargetType { get; set; }
}
```

You will initialize it something like this:

```
   new HomePageMenuItem { Id = 1, Title = "Logout", IsHome= true) }
```

Then in your click event, you check this property and perform the action accordingly

```
if(Obj.IsHome)
{
    //Code to Pop
}
```

Comment: I dont have a click event where do I put this if(Obj.IsHome)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a login page to navigate to the master detail page. When you click logout in master details page, it would navigation to the root page as logout page.

I think `Navigation.PopToRootAsync()` is not a good choice, you could set the main page at runtime directly. And please note, MasterDetailPage is designed to be a root page, there is no need to use `Navigation.PopToRootAsync()` to go back to root page.

This the code set the logout as root page.

```
void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item.Title == "Logout")
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage =new LogoutPageCS();
            }
            else
            {
                Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
                masterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
                IsPresented = false;
            }

        }
    }
```

[image]

For more details, you could download the source file from MasterDetailsDemo folder of GitHub.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

Comment: I used poptoroot to eliminate all the page so that the login page is the only page open

Comment: But for master detail pag, this method would not works. The master details page with all the detail pages is root page.